# RealBasic: execute shell commands

Tags: sqlite, csv, realbasic

I need to load a CSV file into an sqlite DB using Realbasic.
There is no problem doing this as described in [this](http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=ImportingFiles) tutorial.

Can you help me to do this with RealBasic.

I am trying to use the Shell class:

```
Dim folder As FolderItem = GetFolderItem("")

Dim sh As Shell = new Shell
sh.Mode = 2

If Not sh.IsRunning Then
  sh.Execute "sh"   
End If

sh.Write( "cd " + folder.ShellPath )  
sh.Write( "sqlite3 " + App.GetDatabaseName() + ".sqlite" )  
sh.Write( ".separator "",""")

sh.Write( ".import " + FileName + " " + TableName )
```

PS: there are no error messages during execution, in Shell. But the data does not get imported into the table.

How to fix it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try using WriteLine instead of Write to send your commands.

```
sh.WriteLine( "cd " + folder.ShellPath )  
sh.WriteLine( "sqlite3 " + App.GetDatabaseName() + ".sqlite" )  
sh.WriteLine( ".separator "",""")

sh.WriteLine( ".import " + FileName + " " + TableName )
```